# Creating a bridge to connect a router and a proxy server

Tags: linux, proxy, bridge

There is a proxy server which I have no control over. It is completely blocked and firewalled. I want my device to connect to the internet through the proxy without having to enter the proxy details. So, I want to create a sort of a network bridge that sits between the proxy server and the router. 
I want to send data over http and coAp ports.
There is a LAN cable from the proxy server to which the router is connected and the linux machine is connected to the router's ethernet port.

```
                ┌────────┐    ┌─────────┐    ┌────────┐ -> Device1
                │ Proxy  │    │ Linux   │    │        │
The internet -> │ Server │ -> │ Bridge  │ -> │ Router │ -> Device2
                │        │    │         │    │        │
                └────────┘    └─────────┘    └────────┘ -> Device3
```

I want the linux machine to act as a bridge between my devices and the proxy server; ultimately the internet. The requests from the devices can be sent directly to the linux machine by a simple TCP server/client connection. I want the Linux machine to reroute those requests to the proxy server using the required proxy settings.
I have found that a transparent proxy can be set up on the Linux bridge which can then do the rerouting. Now, what changes would have to be made in the iptables for this to work as I am new to them. Also, I couldn't find any specific answer to this problem. Maybe I was looking at the wrong place.

Comment: If this is a work environment you could be breaching your organisation's IT Policy.

Comment: When you say "_proxy_" do you mean "_web proxy_"? Similarly, when you say "_connect to the Internet_" do you really mean "_access websites_"?

Comment: You should really specify what protocol(s) you expect to be able to pass through the proxy; for example, is https supposed to work? Because if yes, that opens a whole new can of worms. Otherwise, for http only, you just need a Linux box with proxy arp enabled and a DNAT rule to shift http traffic to the proxy ip:port. If the proxy can act as a transparent proxy and doesn't need authentication, this should work.

Comment: I want to pass http and coAp. So if I set up a transparent proxy (squid), it should b able to redirect my requests automatically as the Linux system itself would be connected to the internet through the proxy. So, I will just need to send my requests to the proxy server and it will then send it to the internet through th network it is connected to.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information. If you put some here in the comments it can often get overlooked. Help us help you!